# How to change the first day of the week in YouTrack?

Tags: date, calendar, youtrack

Is there a way to change the first day of the week in the JetBrains YouTrack Cloud software? Right now week starts from Sunday, which affects all calendars in all widgets in YT. I want to change the first day of the week to Monday.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change it for a single user. Would like to change it as default for all newly created users. But don't know about that yet.

Changing it for a user go to your profile or as admin `Access Management -> Users` and click a user name.

In the General tab near the bottom you can set the First Day of Week for this user.

[image]